# importance feature xgboost for text predictions

Tags: python, nlp, text-mining, xgboost

i have two text file for rating review positive and negative after the preprocessing the  data with nlp i make prediction with XGboost 
and i am tried to get importance feature as categorical variable but i got the number. how can i interpreted the number to categorical variable??

[image]

```
from xgboost import plot_importance
plot_importance(classifierXG, max_num_features=10)
pyplot.show()
```

Comment: The xx in names `fxx` should be the column number, when you are converting from text to index, you need to save the mapping so that you can convert it back.

Comment: thanks for replay but how can i save the mapping

Comment: how did you vectorize your data? If you used some sort of library, for example sklearn or keras, that object should have the mapping dictionary/list.

Comment: # Creating the BOW model
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
vectorizer = CountVectorizer(max_features = 101, min_df = 3, max_df = 0.6, stop_words = stopwords.words('arabic'))
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus).toarray()    
vectorizer.get_feature_names() 

# Creating the Tf-Idf Model
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfTransformer
transformer = TfidfTransformer()
X = transformer.fit_transform(X).toarray()
transformer.get_feature_names()

Comment: Checkout the two objects `vectorizer` and `transformer`, they should have attribute called `vocabulary_`, that's the mapping dictionary, and you can invert it as well depends on how you need to use it.

Comment: what its better stemming and lemmatization for Arabic text? and can i used  both
i am trying to use stop word and after that make prediction to classification. when used stop word without stemming or lemmatization i got no thing.  so to get better performance for Arabic text what its better to used